# How to write raw unicode ruby string unprocessed

Tags: ruby, unicode, encoding

when I run in rails console, Ruby automatically changes my string:

```
2.7.1 :124 > "\u001b!\u0010\u001bE\u0001"
 => "\e!\u0010\eE\u0001"
```

(from "u001b" into "\e")

How to do this if I still want to maintain the \u001b ?

Comment: `\u001b` is a way to _specify_ Unicode codepoint U+001B in a _string literal_. Ruby doesn't preserve that input format. What you see is the result of `String#inspect` which is not aware of your literal. Here's another example: `"\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F"` becomes `"Hello"`. You can't tell Ruby to keep those escape sequences.

Comment: @Stefan hmm. So, I have this requirement to show it in this string literal form for like a bluetooth printing service which I think should be in that specific format. Do you know any workaround?

Comment: Can you explain the specific requirements? It’s not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.